# Android add Custom View xml to Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been strugling to add a Custom View to my main activity. The custom view is a "side menu" which should be loaded twice on my main activity.

This is my code:

- The SideMenu custom class
- The SideMenu xml file
- And the MainActivity xml file

public class SideMenu extends View {

```
    Context mContext;
    List<MenuItem> menuItemList;

    public SideMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        MenuItemAdapter adapter = new MenuItemAdapter(getContext(), menuItemList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final MenuItem item = (MenuItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)mContext;
                activity.loadContent(item);
            }
        });
    }

    public SideMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

This is the SideMenu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerView"></ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the main xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.dbl.SideMenu
        android:id="@+id/left_side_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="100dp"></com.example.dbl.SideMenu>
```

What is wrong with my code? Should I inflate the custom view somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`public class SideMenu extends View {`

View can't have siblings (eg. hosting other views). For that you need a `ViewGroup` or one of its sublcasses.

> Should I inflate the custom view somehow?

it depends from the constructor you are using. Assuming that you are declaring the siblings of your custom `ViewGroup` directly in the xml, then, that shouldn't be necessary. If you are instantiating the `ViewGroup` programmatically, then you might to add `View`s to it as well